# Do clerics have to prepare ritual spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rituals

I was looking over the cleric spellcasting, and realised that clerics know all their spells automatically, and get to prepare the spells from the entire spell list.

Since rituals don't have to be prepared, **does that mean a cleric can always cast any ritual spell if they have a the spell levels for it?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, your assumption that rituals do not have to be prepared is wrong.

> You
>   can
>   cast
>   a
>   cleric
>   spell
>   as
>   a
>   ritual
>   if
>   that
>   spell
>   has
>   the
>   ritual
>   tag
>   **and
>   you
>   have
>   the
>   spell
>   prepared.**

You might be thinking of wizards, who don't have to prepare rituals, but that's because their ritual spellcasting explicitly says so:

> You
>   can
>   cast
>   a
>   wizard
>   spell
>   as
>   a
>   ritual
>   if
>   that
>   spell
>   has
>   the
>   ritual
>   tag
>   and
>   you
>   have
>   the
>   spell
>   in
>   your
>   spellbook.
>   You
>   don’t
>   need
>   to
>   have
>   the
>   spell
>   prepared.

Comment: Wizards are the only class in 5E who can do this. Every other class must Know or Prepare a spell to use it as a ritual.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing that up. @guildsbounty

Comment: Unless they have the Ritual Caster feat, which grants you Ritual spells in a separate book that you can cast as Rituals without preparation. http://gdnd.wikidot.com/feats#toc36

Comment: @guildsbounty that's almost true except for specifically pact of the tome warlocks with the book of ancient secrets invocation.

Answer (score 12):

From the PHB, p.58:

> You can cast a cleric spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual
>   tag and you have the spell prepared.

So you still need to prepare the spell.