# Do ritual spells need an unused spell slot to be cast as rituals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rituals

I don't talk of Wizards which clearly have an exception with their spell book to preparation and casting of rituals. In my specific situation I ask about a 
Cleric or Warlock with the Ritual Caster feat casting a ritual.

Would a Cleric or Warlock with no spell slots left for the day but originally prepared the ritual spell still be able to cast it as a ritual despite lacking spell slots for it?

Comment: I have removed the question about the preparation of ritual spells as part of that question has already been answered [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102864) and we have a one question one answer policy here. If you still wish that question answered, please do so in a new question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Ritual casting does not require spell slots

> The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than
> normal. It also doesn’t expend a spell slot.

Clearly you don't need to use a slot to cast a ritual spell, and thus there is no reason you would need to have one available. To cast a ritual spell you simply cast it using the ritual casting rules. No slots needed.

Requiring such a thing would completely undercut the usefulness of ritual spells since using slots is what casting as a ritual is intended to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

## No

The section on rituals in the Player's Handbook states:

> The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. It also doesn’t expend a spell slot

No matter what source your ritual spells come from, you don't need a spell slot to cast them as long as you have a feature to cast rituals with.